# Can I use asm function with a c - string variable instead of a string literal as an argument?

Tags: c, inline-assembly

I did something like this :

> > char command [] = "Some assmebly code";
> >
> > asm volatile(command);

It didnt work. Specifically, I get the following error : 
`Expected string literal before command.`

So, can I only use string literals with C inline assembly ? I really want to be able to use string variables like above. How can I achieve this effect ?

Comment: Write the text to a file and `system()` the assembler with that file.

Comment: Also related: [C/C++ inline assembler with instructions in string variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47113280) for an MSVC syntax version of the same question (which has the same answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know asm code fragment are inlined during compilation phase, not run-time. Which means you can't do what you are doing.

As pmg suggested, you could do it by calling external commands, but it would mean user would need to have all the tools installed.